# Django: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: python, django

this is list of some of the URLs I am using for a Django project.

```
url(r'^pt_data/$', views.preliminary_data, name='Preliminary Data'),
    url(r'^pt_test_detail/$', views.pt_test_detail, name='Pt Test Detail'),
    url(r'^pt_test_testdetail/$', views.pt_test_test_detail, name='Pt Test Detail '),
    url(r'^pt_test_syllabus/$', views.pt_test_syllabus, name='Pt Test Detail '),  # Detail about the syllabus
    url(r'^test/individual/graph', views.test_individual_graph, name='Test Individual Graph')
```

Except test/individual/graph api, no other url is found on server. I have corresponding functions written in views. I get following error, for reasons unknown.

The requested URL /pt_test_syllabus was not found on this server.
Someone please tell what am i missing.

Comment: Please include the base urls.py

Comment: Can you also post the error traceback?

Comment: Perhaps, the problem is in the slash at the end?

Comment: paste full traceback (error) and urls.py

Comment: Thanks Philip,  I turned debug=true. error traceback helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs only match when there is a `/` at the end, and you're testing without that.

By default, if an URL without ending slash isn't found, Django automatically retries the URL with a slash appended to it. You appear to have turned that off.

Check that:

- The `APPEND_SLASH` setting is True.
- `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` is in the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the missing trailing (at the end) slash `/`, make it:

```
url(r'^pt_test_syllabus', views.pt_test_syllabus, name='Pt Test Detail '),
```

or simply, request the page at `/py_test_syllabus/` - note the `/` at the end.